# Issues with the design of Launcher icon

Tags: android

I tried to change the ic_launcher.png icon from Android Studio's Config Image Asset. You can see its screenshot below:

[image: image 1]

But, When I deploy the app on the device, the ic_launcher icon seems the smaller than other icons.

[image: image 2]

I used photoshop and designed launcher icon. I, also,  used Launcher Icon Generator to make the ic_launcher. The result is same.

The dimensions I used in photoshop to design the image for ic_launcher was :616x208 png.

Comment: Please provide answers below, not as edits to the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use Android Asset Studio's Launcher Icon Generator. A web implementation is [here](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html). Your design will be automatically resized to support various screen sizes. Just upload your design, grab the .zip and extract it to res directory.

Make the *Padding = 0%* and *Shape = None* on that page.

Comment: I did what you say , but it's the same , I do n't know what is going on?

Comment: I made the Shape -10 it bigger but still not the same size with the other icons

Comment: try a 256x256 icon / or try removing all other icons except xxxhdpi.

Comment: I used 512X512 and worked , but if I upload the same image  to Launcher Icon Generator or Config Image Asset the issue back , I did your suggestion and deleted all but the same

Comment: You can use 512x512 image. But, check them on different phonee too.

Comment: I used nexus 6p and galaxy s3 worked fine , but correct me If I wrong about what I did , I copy and past the same image 512X512 to all folders in mipmap ? it's worked but I think this is not a good practice

Comment: Yeah, it isn't. Infact, even if your launcher icon is smaller than others, don't worry about it.